# Finding the correct traversal path for a packet

Tags: unetstack

[image: Common Link simulation]

Suppose a scenario similar to the above image where Node-A and Node-B are sending data to Node-D via Node-C. Node-A and Node-B each sent one data packet to Node-D.  Node-A sent one msg with msg-id = 1 which is received at Node-C with msg-id = 1 and Node-B sent one msg with msg-id = 3 which is received at node-C with msg-id = 3. Now, how I will get to know that the msg forwarded from Node-C with msg-id = 2 is the msg from Node-A or Node-B and msg forwarded from Node-C with msg-id = 4 is the msg from Node-A or Node-B? How I will follow the correct path while traversing the trace.json file of simulation?

Comment: With just the data you show, you wouldn't. Because of this, some kind of source address is usually added to packets if knowing where they came from is important.

Comment: Yeah, that is the problem I am facing. In the trace.json file, there is no source information in Node-C's events.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The `trace.json` file has information about the thread of events and stimulus that is related to each event. This may provide you the relevant information for your tracing.

To illustrate the idea, I take an example of how the `ranging` agent works. Other agents such as `router` work similarly, so you can use the same idea for tracing routed frames.

See the following entry from a `trace.json` output of a ranging simulation:

```json
{
  "time":1645606042088,
  "component":"ranging::org.arl.unet.localization.Ranging/A",
  "threadID":"88b89b82-eb37-4ac5-83da-3695acb80e7f",
  "stimulus":{"clazz":"org.arl.unet.phy.RxFrameNtf","messageID":"88b89b82-eb37-4ac5-83da-3695acb80e7f","performative":"INFORM","sender":"phy","recipient":"#phy__ntf"},
  "response":{"clazz":"org.arl.unet.phy.TxFrameReq","messageID":"ee9f72f5-5753-4d46-a885-9e446bbf9746","performative":"REQUEST","recipient":"phy"}
}
```

This entry shows that the received frame (`RxFrameNtf`) with ID `88b89b82...` caused the transmission of a new frame (`TxFrameReq`) with ID `ee9f72f5...`. The `threadID` entry can also be helpful, as the same `threadID` is maintained for the whole chain of events within a single node.

Each of your frames from nodes A and B will have unique IDs, and so will each of the frames relayed by node C. The `trace.json` entry corresponding to each relay transmission should tell you which `stimulus` (frame from node A or B) resulted in the transmission.

For your application, I extract a few of the JSON entries from your `trace.json` to illustrate this:

```json
{
  "time":10000, "component":"router::org.arl.unet.net.Router/A", "threadID":"2e37d6d6-a3d2-4e0f-aacc-456efdae91bb",
  "stimulus":{"clazz":"org.arl.unet.DatagramReq", "messageID":"2e37d6d6-a3d2-4e0f-aacc-456efdae91bb", "performative":"REQUEST", "sender":"simulator", "recipient":"router"},
  "response":{"clazz":"org.arl.unet.DatagramReq", "messageID":"54a55a12-4051-4934-88bc-beb4fa28c548", "performative":"REQUEST", "recipient":"uwlink"}
}
{
  "time":10491, "component":"uwlink::org.arl.unet.link.ReliableLink/A", "threadID":"54a55a12-4051-4934-88bc-beb4fa28c548",
  "stimulus":{"clazz":"org.arl.unet.DatagramReq", "messageID":"54a55a12-4051-4934-88bc-beb4fa28c548", "performative":"REQUEST", "sender":"router", "recipient":"uwlink"},
  "response":{"clazz":"org.arl.unet.phy.TxFrameReq", "messageID":"87757d67-7510-4856-a9ee-a27924f9548a", "performative":"REQUEST", "recipient":"phy"}
}
{
  "time":10491, "component":"phy::org.arl.unet.sim.HalfDuplexModem/A", "threadID":"87757d67-7510-4856-a9ee-a27924f9548a",
  "stimulus":{"clazz":"org.arl.unet.phy.TxFrameReq", "messageID":"87757d67-7510-4856-a9ee-a27924f9548a", "performative":"REQUEST", "sender":"uwlink", "recipient":"phy"},
  "response":{"clazz":"org.arl.unet.sim.HalfDuplexModem$TX", "messageID":"31b892fd-1b2c-40b1-a1d6-4dc457f57a2c", "performative":"INFORM", "recipient":"phy"}
}
{
  "time":11870, "component":"phy::org.arl.unet.sim.HalfDuplexModem/C", "threadID":"31b892fd-1b2c-40b1-a1d6-4dc457f57a2c",
  "stimulus":{"clazz":"org.arl.unet.sim.HalfDuplexModem$TX", "messageID":"31b892fd-1b2c-40b1-a1d6-4dc457f57a2c", "performative":"INFORM", "sender":"phy", "recipient":"phy"},
  "response":{"clazz":"org.arl.unet.phy.RxFrameNtf", "messageID":"5cd195ef-74b0-4394-8f9a-9077de08bc56", "performative":"INFORM", "sender":"phy", "recipient":"#phy__ntf"}
}
{
  "time":11870, "component":"router::org.arl.unet.net.Router/C", "threadID":"5cd195ef-74b0-4394-8f9a-9077de08bc56",
  "stimulus":{"clazz":"org.arl.unet.phy.RxFrameNtf", "messageID":"5cd195ef-74b0-4394-8f9a-9077de08bc56", "performative":"INFORM", "sender":"phy", "recipient":"#phy__ntf"},
  "response":{"clazz":"org.arl.unet.DatagramReq", "messageID":"e9ecfc32-ff9a-4750-99d5-b3b462dcd660", "performative":"REQUEST", "recipient":"uwlink"}
}
{
  "time":12259, "component":"uwlink::org.arl.unet.link.ReliableLink/C", "threadID":"e9ecfc32-ff9a-4750-99d5-b3b462dcd660",
  "stimulus":{"clazz":"org.arl.unet.DatagramReq", "messageID":"e9ecfc32-ff9a-4750-99d5-b3b462dcd660", "performative":"REQUEST", "sender":"router", "recipient":"uwlink"},
  "response":{"clazz":"org.arl.unet.phy.TxFrameReq", "messageID":"76200f60-2334-4f20-88a3-9c2d42a769ad", "performative":"REQUEST", "recipient":"phy"}
}
{
  "time":12259, "component":"phy::org.arl.unet.sim.HalfDuplexModem/C", "threadID":"76200f60-2334-4f20-88a3-9c2d42a769ad",
  "stimulus":{"clazz":"org.arl.unet.phy.TxFrameReq", "messageID":"76200f60-2334-4f20-88a3-9c2d42a769ad", "performative":"REQUEST", "sender":"uwlink", "recipient":"phy"},
  "response":{"clazz":"org.arl.unet.sim.HalfDuplexModem$TX", "messageID":"f3161e4e-1007-4540-8192-f0d7bf80e126", "performative":"INFORM", "recipient":"phy"}
}
{
  "time":13542, "component":"phy::org.arl.unet.sim.HalfDuplexModem/D", "threadID":"f3161e4e-1007-4540-8192-f0d7bf80e126",
  "stimulus":{"clazz":"org.arl.unet.sim.HalfDuplexModem$TX", "messageID":"f3161e4e-1007-4540-8192-f0d7bf80e126", "performative":"INFORM", "sender":"phy", "recipient":"phy"},
  "response":{"clazz":"org.arl.unet.phy.RxFrameNtf", "messageID":"ab5e15a9-27e0-4495-b0b8-f199159cb2a3", "performative":"INFORM", "sender":"phy", "recipient":"#phy__ntf"}
}
{
  "time":13542, "component":"uwlink::org.arl.unet.link.ReliableLink/D", "threadID":"ab5e15a9-27e0-4495-b0b8-f199159cb2a3",
  "stimulus":{"clazz":"org.arl.unet.phy.RxFrameNtf", "messageID":"ab5e15a9-27e0-4495-b0b8-f199159cb2a3", "performative":"INFORM", "sender":"phy", "recipient":"#phy__ntf"},
  "response":{"clazz":"org.arl.unet.DatagramNtf", "messageID":"bb534fc0-47ec-4b2d-8124-07af87528d37", "performative":"INFORM", "recipient":"#uwlink__ntf"}
}
{
  "time":13542, "component":"router::org.arl.unet.net.Router/D", "threadID":"bb534fc0-47ec-4b2d-8124-07af87528d37",
  "stimulus":{"clazz":"org.arl.unet.DatagramNtf", "messageID":"bb534fc0-47ec-4b2d-8124-07af87528d37", "performative":"INFORM", "sender":"uwlink", "recipient":"#uwlink__ntf"},
  "response":{"clazz":"org.arl.unet.DatagramNtf", "messageID":"5e660793-9a44-4341-8843-fc7fa91aa450", "performative":"INFORM", "recipient":"#router__ntf"}
}
```

These entries show the sequence of events that occurred:

- time `10000`: `DatagramReq` from `router@A` to `uwlink@A`
- time `10491`: `TxFrameReq` from `uwlink@A` to `phy@A`
- time `10491`: `TX` from `phy@A` to `phy@C`
- time `11870`: `RxFrameNtf` from `phy@C` (publish on topic)
- time `11870`: `DatagramReq` from `router@C` to `uwlink@C`
- time `12259`: `TxFrameReq` from `uwlink@C` to `phy@C`
- time `12259`: `TX` from `phy@C` to `phy@D`
- time `13542`: `RxFrameNtf` from `phy@D` (publish on topic)
- time `13542`: `DatagramNtf` from `uwlink@D` (publish on topic)
- time `13542`: `DatagramNtf` from `router@D` (publish on topic)

You should find that each JSON entry's `response.messageID` corresponds to the next JSON entry's `stimulus.messageID`. This allows you to follow through the sequence of events.

Comment: I created the same topology and simulated it for some time.  I cannot find a similar logged event in the trace.json file as you mentioned in the reply. find the simulation script and trace.json file  https://drive.google.com/drive/folders/16yvOwN5guQVjH2z4DjIzVFfoKrg_jwdL?usp=sharing

Comment: I have updated the answer to show how it works with the `trace.json` you provided.

Comment: I created a 3-node network, where Node-A is sending a packet after every 5 sec to Node-C via Node-B. I simulated this network for 1 minute. While analyzing the trace.json file I get to know that in some cases there are more than one TxFrameReq for one DatagrameReq at Node-B. why it is happening? [here] (https://drive.google.com/drive/folders/1rpJfPyclFXdT-a0HdwlibsAlDkQb27sm?usp=sharing) I am sharing the simulation code and trace.json file. for the 2nd packet ```A```(10215)TX -> ```B```(11032)RxFrameNtf -> ```B```(11032)DatagramReq -> ```B```(13677)TxFrameReq / ```B```(21463)TxFrameReq

Comment: Sir, I explained my query in the next question. Please help me with that.