# Calculating End-to-End delay for multihop simulation in UnetStack

Tags: unetstack

[image]

I created a 3-node network, where Node-A sends data packets to Node-C via Node-B after every 5 sec. The simulation time is 1 minute. So, in 60 seconds Node-A will send 11 packets to Node-C. According to the [This](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/72475873/finding-the-correct-traversal-path-for-a-packet) reply, I analyzed the trace.json file for each transmission from source(Node-A) to destination(Node-C).
I have some doubts:-

1. For some packets, at Node-B(intermediate node) there is more than one TxFrameReq for one DatagrameReq (example 2nd and 4th packet transmission). why it is happening?
2. In the above scenario what will be the end-to-end delay for that transmission?
3. For some transmissions end-to-end delay is more than 15 seconds plus. Is it correct or I am making some mistake in the end-to-end delay calculation. I am calculating the end-to-end delay by substracting the TX time of Node-A to the RxFrameNtf time of Node-C.

[here](https://drive.google.com/drive/folders/1rpJfPyclFXdT-a0HdwlibsAlDkQb27sm?usp=sharing) I am sharing the simulation code, trace.json file, and a pdf containing the timing of the required events at each node.

Comment: The number of `TxFrameReq` corresponding to one `DatagramReq` depends on the amount of data to be delivered, and the underlying PHY frame size. Higher layer protocols (e.g. LINK, TRANSPORT) usually support fragmentation/reassembly to allow delivery of datagrams larger than a single frame.

Comment: End-to-end delays can be in the order of tens of seconds, depending on the MAC allowing access to the channel when multiple nodes are contending.

Comment: how can set fragmentation as false?

Comment: Send small enough datagrams so that fragmentation isn't needed.